# Power BI Incremental Refresh problems

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

Hope you are all well :)

So we started introducing Incremental Refresh on our Power BI Cloud's Dataflow, as we would like to reduce the amount of data which our MSSQL Server needs to prepare for Power BI.

so we set the incremental refresh to:

[image: Power BI Incremental Refresh Settings]

Now the problem it causes is that it keeps sending the query to MSSQL in blow format:

```
select [_].[BOOKING_ID],

    [_].[ORDER_NUMBER],

    [_].[PROCESS_START_TS],

    [_].[PROCESS_TARGET_TS],

    [_].[PROCESS_COMPLETE_TS],

    [_].[SLA_MET],

    [_].[TS_STOP_REASON],

    [_].[DOCUMENT_TYPE]

from [dbo].[view1] as [_]

where [_].[PROCESS_COMPLETE_TS] >= convert(datetime2, '2021-01-04 00:00:00') and [_].[PROCESS_COMPLETE_TS] < convert(datetime2, '2021-01-05 00:00:00')
```

it literally sends 28 queries such as above to the server, instead of sending it once like:

```
where [_].[PROCESS_COMPLETE_TS] >= convert(datetime2, '2021-01-04 00:00:00') and [_].[PROCESS_COMPLETE_TS] < getdate()
```

This query is very CPU Expensive, and I rather have it done once instead of 28 times.

Is there any fix to this?

Also, is there anyway to enforce the 28 days date range?
As Power BI sends queries from start of January this year, which is way out of the range we defined.

Many thanks in advance.